# Solve sequence equation in PHP

Tags: php, math, sequence

Guys how to solve this kind of sequenced equation in PHP:

```
$D = array(120, 30, 10, 55...);
S1=D1
S2=D1-D2
S3=D1-D2-D3
```

Comment: least clear (and duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614044/how-to-solve-equation-in-php) question of the day

Comment: [Like this?](https://eval.in/186736)

Comment: you cant, because you got D not D1. please fix the var names.

Comment: Scrowler it should be dynamic, maybe i will have S5, S10 Or S23.

Comment: levi,  $D it's array, so i shall get it through loop for.

Comment: @Refresh [like this then](https://eval.in/186755)? The answer below is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$D = array(120, 30, 10, 55);
$S[] = array_shift($D);

foreach ($D as $k => $v) {
    $S[$k + 1] = $S[$k] - $v;
}

print_r($S);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 120
    [1] => 90
    [2] => 80
    [3] => 25
)
```

Comment: thanks! Worked. Can you help me with this equation too, please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614044/how-to-solve-equation-in-php Couldn't figured it out.